# Calculate difference in Oracle table from sum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, case

I have a table which looks as followed:

```
ID | Value
A  | 2
A  | 5
A  | 6 
B  | 1
B  | 7
B  | -3
```

I am currently using a statement as followed

```
select ID, sum(VALUE) 
where ...
group by ID.
```

Now I need the difference from A and B.

Could anyone send me on the right path? I am working with Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id = 'A' THEN "Value" ELSE 0 END) -
       SUM(CASE WHEN id = 'B' THEN "Value" ELSE 0 END) "Difference"
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76d99b9dc40c04ba37faabb1547d4a9f).